# Unable to load dynamic library For Multiple ".so" files (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and have php 5.6 and php 7.3 installed. I am trying to check php -v and I keep getting the following errors in the output. When I go to the /usr/lib/php/20180731 DIR I see the following with ll command. I do notice the .so files that my php -v command is outputting as "missing" are not in the Directory. Why is this the case? How do I find those .so files so that this error goes away?

Editing to show pecl install commands for sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv

Thank you.

Full Output

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:48:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.13, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

DIR ll output:

```
/usr/lib/php/20180731$ ll
total 11128
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Jan  8 08:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root    4096 Jan  8 07:37 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34928 Dec 18 07:48 bcmath.so
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Jan  8 07:49 build/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30824 Dec 18 07:48 calendar.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14440 Dec 18 07:48 ctype.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  161896 Dec 18 07:48 dom.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   84072 Dec 18 07:48 exif.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5425264 Dec 18 07:48 fileinfo.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   59496 Dec 18 07:48 ftp.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  104552 Dec 18 07:48 gd.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14440 Dec 18 07:48 gettext.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   43112 Dec 18 07:48 iconv.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   43112 Dec 18 07:48 json.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1599624 Dec 18 07:48 mbstring.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  133224 Dec 18 07:48 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  247416 Dec 18 07:48 mysqlnd.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  506352 Dec 18 07:48 opcache.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   26728 Dec 18 07:48 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  108648 Dec 18 07:48 pdo.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  268392 Dec 18 07:48 phar.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34920 Dec 18 07:48 posix.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30824 Dec 18 07:48 readline.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14440 Dec 18 07:48 shmop.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   51304 Dec 18 07:48 simplexml.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   88168 Dec 18 07:48 sockets.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14440 Dec 18 07:48 sysvmsg.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   10344 Dec 18 07:48 sysvsem.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14440 Dec 18 07:48 sysvshm.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18536 Dec 18 07:48 tokenizer.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30824 Dec 18 07:48 wddx.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1880600 Dec 19 04:16 xdebug.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30824 Dec 18 07:48 xmlreader.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   47208 Dec 18 07:48 xml.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   47208 Dec 18 07:48 xmlwriter.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30824 Dec 18 07:48 xsl.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   63592 Dec 18 07:48 zip.so

sudo pecl install sqlsrv

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
pecl/sqlsrv is already installed and is the same as the released version 5.7.1preview
install failed
```

pdo_sqlsrv is the one that really fails

```
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1.tgz (175,658 bytes)
.....................................done: 175,658 bytes
35 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20190902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20190902
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for pdo_sqlsrv support... yes, shared
checking for PDO includes... /usr/include/php/20190902/ext
checking for PDO_SQLSRV headers... /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
(cached) (cached) checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_dbh.cpp -o pdo_dbh.lo
mkdir .libs
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_dbh.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_dbh.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_parser.cpp -o pdo_parser.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_parser.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_parser.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_util.cpp -o pdo_util.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_util.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_util.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_init.cpp -o pdo_init.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_init.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_init.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_stmt.cpp -o pdo_stmt.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_stmt.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_stmt.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_conn.cpp -o shared/core_conn.lo
mkdir shared/.libs
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_conn.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o shared/.libs/core_conn.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_results.cpp -o shared/core_results.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_results.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o shared/.libs/core_results.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp -o shared/core_stream.lo
 g++ -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVhleho/pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o shared/.libs/core_stream.o
/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp:209:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘size_t (*)(php_stream*, char*, size_t) {aka long unsigned int (*)(_php_stream*, char*, long unsigned int)}’ to ‘ssize_t (*)(php_stream*, char*, size_t) {aka long int (*)(_php_stream*, char*, long unsigned int)}’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
Makefile:206: recipe for target 'shared/core_stream.lo' failed
make: *** [shared/core_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: `php-mcrypt` is deprecated and not shipped anymore.  As for the sqlsrv issues, you don't have the PHP plugins to work with SQL Server, and no PHP package containing that is available by default in Ubuntu - this said, if you have a customized PHP installation, then you need to probably use `pecl` to install the sqlsrv.so plugin.

Comment: I will purge the mcrypt since it is php 7.3. I tries to use pecl to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv and it did not worK. I will edit my post to show the output of the pecl install commands

Comment: I also don't have mcrypt installed anymore so idk why php is looking for the mcrypt.so file?

Comment: did you disable it in the PHP configuration?  Also, if you are trying to use mcrypt in the scripts it'll try and access it. Also, how is PHP installed on your system  From the repositories or from somewhere else?

Comment: Disabling mcrypt using phpdismod worked! Now for the sqlsrv stuff...I installed php using a PPA and have it configured to use FPM/FastCGI